# JavaFx with SQLite deployment using JPakcage: App Doesnt load upon installation

Tags: sqlite, javafx, jpackage

So I'm trying to deploy a JavaFX (with SQLite) Desktop Application

- I'm using open-JDK-16, java SDK-16, and SQLite.3.20.1 JDBC driver
- I'm working on Intellij IDEA(2020.3.2 Community Edition) and when I run my code it works fine
- If the database file does not exist, one will be created and a table inside it too will also be created and populated with some data [see my project folder](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1x-MlsIDGW-IN8vbBJGCUWPnz5TBxBP4D?usp=sharing).
- Upon deployment with JPackage an installer is created successfully and I can install it with no issues

**But when I run the executable it does not do anything, but the console window displays the output below, on execution.**

Thank you so much in advance, to anyone who will help me resolve this issue

here is an error I received from the window console

```
Exception in Application start method
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(Unknown Source)
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(Unknown Source)
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$2(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: java/sql/Driver
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.findClassOnClassPathOrNull(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClassOrNull(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
        at sample.Main.Connector(Main.java:27)
        at sample.Main.start(Main.java:17)
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$9(Unknown Source)
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$12(Unknown Source)
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$10(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Unknown Source)
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$11(Unknown Source)
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(Unknown Source)
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$runLoop$3(Unknown Source)
        ... 1 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: java.sql.Driver
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        ... 22 more
Exception running application sample.Main
```

Comment: How are you invoking jpacakge? Is anything printed if you run the program from the console? (on Windows you might need to add the `--win-console` option)

Comment: thank you for the quick feedback @JornVernee I tried adding the option and the console window appears with some errors and then disappears, I cant really capture the error

Comment: I've modified my question to display the error message I got from the console

Comment: How are you invoking jpackage? (which options etc.)

Comment: I solved the issue, I was missing the java.sql module in my module list, once I added it every thing went well, thank you for the support

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve the problem just make sure you have included all the required modules, I was missing a **java.sql** module  once I added that my problem was solved